# OrientDB for storing network monitoring log data

Tags: java, csv, logging, orientdb, graph-databases

I have a problem when storing network monitoring log data in OrientDB. They are collected from 2 different sources and stored in csv files (totally there are ~200k records/day) every 1 minute.  Let say they are alert and waf which have common properties like sourceIP, destinationIP.

In term of OrientDB data model, I defined 2 vertices including: `Alert`, `WAF` and 1 edge which is `connect`. This edge stores relation info between `Alert` and `WAF` when they have same sourceIP and destinationIP.

While parsing and inserting them to OrientDB, alert is stored normally. However, I need to retrieve a related alert from `Alert` for creating relation and storing in `connect` every time when inserting waf. In other words, there are 100k waf records need to be inserted, there will be 100k times retrieving related alert for creating relation in edge.

Certainly, with this implementation, current inserting performance is quite slow. I tried adding 1.1M records which has 19k alert and it took ~43 mins.

I am wondering that my current approach is going wrong way or any better solution for this?

This is an example for my implementation in Java.

```
void importCSV(OrientGraph graph, List<Alert> alerts, List<WAF> wafs)
{
     for(Alert a: alerts) {
        graph.createVertex ......
     }
     for(WAF w: wafs) {
        Vertex v = graph.createVertex ......
        //check related alert which is not only in alerts list but also in DB.
        Vertex alert = findRelatedAlert(Graph, <conditions>);
        Edge relation = graph.createEdge(alert, v);
     }
     graph.commit()
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is it got a negative vote?

Comment: There is simply not enough information here to debug your *slow* system, I realize that this is pseudo-code but the `Vertex` in your first loop does not seem to be used.  Aside from this, you need to ascertain what is slowing down your system

Comment: This question is not for debugging. Actually once `graph.createVertex` is called, a vertex will be added after commiting. Let me remove it from pseudo code to be clear.

Comment: Could you tellen how you find the alerts? By an id or property?

Comment: mitchken, I find by properties. However, they are indexed. I am thinking whether I should use a cache for alerts data.

Comment: Since you mention there are multiple wafs which need a connection to one singel alert it seems mostly a great idea to bundle those which need the samen. If possible at all.

Comment: I am wondering why I could not answer my own question :-)

Answer (score 1):

What can make the real difference is the right balancing between the heap and the virtual memory used by Memory Mapping, specially on large datasets (GBs, TBs and more) where the in memory cache structures count less than raw IO.
Surely the advice is to look at this [documentation_memory_performance](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Performance-Tuning.html) that shows information and example useful to configure optimally.
In order to speed up the queries, you could add the indexes, whose purpose is to allow an easier recovery of the records ([documentation_index](https://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/Indexes.html))

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I applied an in-memory cache which is just a LinkedHashMap to prevent I/O causes while checking related data.  Finally its performance has a big improvement. It can be 10 times faster.